# when I make margin top for the one image ,then , why the second image moving with it?

Tags: html, css

When I make margin top for the  one  image ,then , why the second image moving  with it?

```
<img src="bgdesert.jpg"  style="margin-top: 18px;">
<img src="bgdesert.jpg" >
```

Comment: Because both of them are statically positioned? Try `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;`, then use `top` instead of `margin-top`.

Answer (score 1):

this is due to **vertical alignement**, You may change it to `top` to avoid this effect :

```css
img {
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/"  style="margin-top: 18px;">
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" >
```

Answer (score -1):

you can put the any img in div and then give float:left for first one

```
<div>
<img src="src="bgdesert.jpg""  style="margin-top: 18px; float: left">
</div>
<div>
<img src="bgdesert.jpg" >
</div>
```